# MS Access 2016 SQL in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake. I have a SQL Server with tables that I have linked in MS Access. I am trying to run a SQL query in Form `OnLoad` to populate a text box based on a value in my form.

Below is my code. The field I want returned *TE* is varchar in MSSQL and short text in Access. I am getting a `'Type Mismatch'` on the textbox. When I try outputting to a `MsgBox` I get:

> 'rst!TE not in collection'.

TN and TN_1 are smallint, in Access they are Number.

```vb
Dim rst As DAO.Database
Set rst = CurrentDb

rst.OpenRecordset "SELECT dbo_STCH.TE FROM dbo_STCH RIGHT JOIN dbo_SCVR ON               dbo_STCH.TN = dbo_SCVR.TN_1 WHERE dbo_SCVR.TN_1=99;"

Me.Text22.Text = rst!TE
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are conflating DAO recordsets and databases and hence the message is correct as the item is not found in collection. Simply initialize *rst* as a recordset and assign it to `OpenRecordset` call.

```vb
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT dbo_STCH.TE FROM dbo_STCH" _
                                  & " RIGHT JOIN dbo_SCVR ON dbo_STCH.TN = dbo_SCVR.TN_1" _
                                  & " WHERE dbo_SCVR.TN_1=99;")

Me.Text22.Text = rst!TE

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: Ok, these are the changes. I get the error 'Object variable or With block variable not set'                                                                                          
       'Dim rst AS Recordset '                                                                                                  
       'rst.OpenRecordset "SELECT..."'

Comment: You are still using your current code and not this answer: `rst.OpenRecordset` means you are trying to open a recordset on a recordset object. Use `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `rst.MoveFirst` to move to the first record of the opened recordset before reading any values from it.

Also as the answer above you have to `Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset`

Comment: Ok, looks like that got me through to the record, but now I get 'You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.'    on my textbox.

Comment: Remove the `.text` part: `Me.Text22 = rst!TE`